# Symbol’s value as variable is void: lsp-server-install-dir

Tags: scala, spacemacs, scala-metals

I've been trying to set up the Scala layer and the Metals backend for spacemacs. I am relatively new to spacemacs and completely new to Scala. Quickly some problems, for which I have no idea how they can be connected to the Scala layer, arised. Firstly I got an error saying "package eldoc not initialized in layer java" despite the fact that I had no java layer installed at the time. I managed to resolve that one by installing the java layer and then deleting a line saying "eldoc" in the file at layers/+lang/java/packages.el.

Afterwards another problem appeared, which I still haven't managed to solve, namely now I get the following message upon opening spacemacs:

```
(Spacemacs) Error in dotspacemacs/user-config: Symbol’s value as variable is void: lsp-server-install-dir
```

I googled right about everything about this error and found absolutely no other reports of such a problem and nothing close to a solution.
I tried experimenting with disabling certain layers in .spacemacs and commenting out the lines I added before the problem appeared, but nothing changes or even more errors and warnings appear.

I am not sure if this is in any way connected, but after trying to install the Haskell IDE Engine into spacemacs a few months back, I got a warning, which still appears whenever I start spacemacs, saying:

```
wrong-type-argument stringp nil
```

This second problem seems to be harmless, so after a few days I gave up on trying to solve it and have been using spacemacs normally until now. This new error about lsp-server-install-dir, however, seems to be more urgent and spacemacs shows a red line at the bottom saying that it might not work correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure for spacemacs, but changing my melpa source from stable to latest fixed my issue (melpa.org instead of stable.melpa.org)